# Oracle SQL: Extracting value after text and before delimeter (or other character)

Tags: oracle

I'd like help on the following issue. I've been having a tough time figuring out how to do it.

So basically, I'd like to get the number value after the text ';a_limit:' and ';limit:' but only up to the semicolon right after.

This is how the data looks like:

```
+------------+--------------------------------------------+
| product id |                 properties                 |
+------------+--------------------------------------------+
|          1 | ;a_limit:99;ccc:1234;limit:1:mmm:xx        |
|          2 | ;a_limit:99;bbb:456;ccc:234;limit:15;nnn:0 |
|          5 | ;a_limit:99;limit:5;mmm:null               |
+------------+--------------------------------------------+
```

This is how I want it to look like:

```
+------------+---------+-------+
| product id | a_limit | limit |
+------------+---------+-------+
|          1 |      99 |     1 |
|          2 |     100 |    15 |
|          5 |      99 |     5 |
+------------+---------+-------+
```

Comment: You shouldn't store values in a single string, when you are interested in the separate values. This is not how a DBMS should be used. And you tagged MySQL and Oracle, but these are two different DBMS. Which one are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't store values in a single string, when you are interested in the separate values. Anyway:

```
select
  product_id,
  to_number(regexp_replace(properties, '^.*;a_limit:([[:digit:]]+).*$', '\1')) as a_limit,
  to_number(regexp_replace(properties, '^.*;limit:([[:digit:]]+).*$', '\1')) as limit
from mytable
order by product_id;
```

The `REGEXP_REPLACE` expressions remove everything from the string except for the numbers.